# Explain this comparator?

Tags: java, comparator

I know that `int maxLength` returns the length of the longest word in the list, but I figured `return arg0.length() - arg1.length();` should return something like `-1` `0` or `1`. So how are those values set to a `.length()`at the end

```
 int maxLength = Collections.max(lst, new Comparator<String>() { //get length of longest word using Collections.max comparator
            @Override
            public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
                return arg0.length() - arg1.length();
            }
        }).length();
```

Comment: _"return arg0.length() - arg1.length(); should return something like -1 0 or 1"_ I don't know where you made this assumption. The doc clearly says: _"Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second."_ So the value is 0 if they are considered equals otherwise a negative or positive value is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this

```
arg0.length() - arg1.length()
```

will return an integer representing how arg0 compares with arg1, if it is 0, both are equal in this logical comparission, if it is -x then arg1 is x greater than arg1, and if it is x, arg0 is x greater than arg1

> could you explain the .length() part as well? how is a 1 set to .length() at the end. –  FatFockFrank just now

this statement is similar to

```
String longestString = Collections.max(lst, new Comparator<String>() { //get length of longest word using Collections.max comparator
            @Override
            public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
                return arg0.length() - arg1.length();
            }
        });

int maxLength = longestString.length();
```

Comment: could you explain the `.length()` part as well? how is a `1` set to `.length()` at the end. Sorry I'm not familiar with this too well

Answer (score 1):

The

```js
return arg0.length() - arg1.length();
```

Returns postive if arg0 is longer, 0 if they are equal in length, and negative if arg1 is longer.  The returned value doesn't matter beyond whether it's positive or negative (or zero), so the actual value beyond that is ignored.  Eg, a returned value of -50 is treated the same as -1.

Answer (score 1):

The Comparator provides a method for comparing two elements.

From the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator)):

> public static  T max(Collection coll, Comparator comp)
>   Returns the maximum element of the given collection, according to the order induced by the specified comparator. All elements in the collection must be mutually comparable by the specified comparator (that is, comp.compare(e1, e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the collection).

Which results in a string (which has the longest length of the strings in `lst`) and `Collections.max(...).length()` will return its length.